# Jquery blur after multiple fields compiled

Tags: jquery

I'd like to generate a text on the fly by taking the data from two input fields after they have been compiled.
I was thinking about function blur, but I would like to generate the text only when both input fields have value.
At the time I made only one field at a time but one overwrites other one.

```
<p><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="text" id="text" /></p>
```

JS

```
$("#name").blur(function(){

   var str = $("#name").val();
   var n = str.substring(0, 1); 
   $('#text').val(n);
});

$("#sname").blur(function(){

   var str = $("#sname").val();
   var s = str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "")
   $('#text').val(s);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f58fn/

How can I do this? thanks

Comment: Start with this and see if you can work the rest out `if ($('#something').val()!=''){}`

Comment: @Popnoodles - I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your logic is correct but you need a check if the input's are actually filled.

Here's how I would do it:

```
$("#name, #sname").bind('input', function () {
    //May you want to show the user that only certain chars are allowed
    var n = $("#name").val( $("#name").val().substring(0, 1)).val();
    var s = $("#sname").val($("#sname").val().replace(/[_\W]+/g, "")).val();
    //check if the input fulfills your needings (may inlcude a check for space, etc.)
    if ($("#sname").val().length && $("#name").val().length) {
        $('#text').val(n + s);
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2uE6/)

Comment: Why are you performing the same substring and replace functions twice?

Comment: @Popnoodles you are perfectly right :) - corrected the answer

Comment: +1 Ok. Aside, there's no need for `> 0` when checking length as it returns falsey/truthy anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by always setting the concatenated value in your third textbox as follows:

```
<p><input type="text" name="name" class="input" id="name" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="sname" class="input" id="sname" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="text" id="text" /></p>

$('.input').blur(function(){
   var value = $("#sname").val() + $("#name").val()
   $("#text").val(value);
});
```

This has the benefit of needing one less event handler, though the first time you bler from "#name" it will uselessly query the value of "#sname", but this would be a pretty negligible overhead.

Comment: You have removed OP's `str.replace` and `str.substring`